# Link causes refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hyperlink, refresh

I try to make a link fire a javascript function wich fires a ajax call to delete an item.

Like so:

```
<a class="delete" href="@item.Product.Id">(x)</a>
```

Clicking the cross caries the id of the product to be deleted.
The only reason the href attribute is there is to carry the value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('.delete').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    deleteItem(id);
    return false;
});
});
```

Ajax call: as requested:

```
function deleteItem(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Shoppingcart/RemoveItem",
    type: "POST",
    data: "id=" + id,
    cache: false,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
    },
    success: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Shoppingcart/Index",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr, status, error);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                success(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

The success function is there to get an updated version of the cart.
And this actually works just fine. However I get a wierd page refresh half way trough the cycle.

I click the link.

the page refreshes and the item is not deleted.

I click the link once more.

the page is not refreshed.

the item is deleted.

Why do I have to click two time and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: why not just use id to hold the product's id?

Comment: try adding `console.log('ready')` as the first line of the ready callback. Maybe you clicked before the `ready` callback was called? `$(document).ready(function(){console.log('ready');});`

Comment: The problem shouldn't be in the code you've quoted, you're doing the right things to prevent the default action. It's probably in `deleteId` instead. But I would ***strongly*** recommend you not put invalid values in `href`. Use a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) instead. Abusing `href` is just a bad idea.

Comment: Why use <a> and onclick!!!! Just use <li> or <div> to prevent conflicts.

Comment: well, `<a>` is styled like a link by default (pointer cursor, underlined, etc) so it's not a bad idea to use it here. the problem is just using `href` for what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @specialscope: Using `a` is useful. Even though you can use CSS and `role` to mimic nearly all of the behaviors user agents give to `a` elements, it's only nearly, and not perfect cross-browser.

Comment: Ok, so a big debate about if I used the link property correctly. before we continue doing that, would you mind taking a look at the updated version of the post including the ajax call? as referred by @T.J.Crowder

Comment: what does `success(result)` do?

Comment: Calling a function that reloads the shoppingcart partial view

Comment: sounds like you should follow what the top-voted answer says, then. try putting an `onclick` directly on your `<a>` tag instead of binding the click event with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct answer is: You don't know what the error is,
because the page is refreshing before you see the error.

Return false prevents the page from refreshing after a click event, but if the code runs into an error before that point...

So you could try to remove the `href` tag and make it an rel (or something else) tag instead. read that and use it for your AJAX call. give the `href` a value like `#` or `#removeItem`.
This will give you the error your craving for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could also use a javascript debugger to see if the code reaches the return statement.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you get such behavior when page the is quite big and the `document.ready` event just hasn't fired yet when you click the link. The second time it may load faster (scripts/css already downloaded and coming from cache).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, have a hidden field or a hidden span to save the "ProductId" and remove the href attribute altogether something like below.

```
<span id="productIdSpan">@item.Product.Id</span>
<a class="delete"></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
     $('.delete').click(function (e) {     
     var id = $("#productIdSpan").html();     
     deleteItem(id);     
     return false; 
  }); 
});
```

**EDIT:
Approach-2:**

You can store the ProductId in the anchor tag's "title" attribute something like below

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
     $(".delete").on("click", function (e) {     
     deleteItem($(this).attr("title"));     
     return false; 
  }); 
});
```

This should solve your problem. Hope this helps!!

Comment: I don't think that item id is expected to be visible

Comment: also what to do if there is > 1 product?

Comment: As I mentioned the id can be hidden and also, there can be one span per link

Comment: you suggest to keep id in #productIdSpan defenitelly could be only 1 span with such ID on the page. There is no explicit reference between a and span

Comment: also empty link (without href) is bad idea. Link may look unclickable in some browsers.

Comment: once again, title would be visible on hover...:) You'd better put span inside the link as first child for example and make it invisible

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:
When you add an **element** to your html **after** the page is loaded ( for example with AJAX ) and you want to have, in any way, fire an event. You have to rebind the click event to the new element.

When the page is loaded and your javascript and jQuery are loaded. The element isn't their yet so they can't find it or interact with it.

So in my situation:

```
function addItem(id, amount) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Shoppingcart/AddItem",
        type: "POST",
        data: "id=" + id + "&amount=" + amount,
        cache: false,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr, status, error);
        },
        success: function () {
            // Calls for the new update version of the shopping cart.
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Shoppingcart/Index",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr, status, error);
                },
                success: function (result) {
//Call the function that changes the html
                        success(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

function success(result) {
    $("#shoppingcart").html(result);
//The tricky part: rebinding the new event.
    $('.delete').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        deleteItem(id);
        return false;
    });
}
```

The delete button did work after a refresh because in that way javascript got reloaded and the element was correctly bound.